# Is there a way to get previous value of an attribute in beforeSave or afterSave?

Tags: parse-platform

For example, I have a class "Photo" which has an attribute "of_album". If I move this photo to another album, I want the new album's photo_count increase by 1 and old album's photo_count decrease by 1. How do I do this in beforeSave or afterSave?

Currently what I'm doing is that in beforeSave, I fetch the photo object by its id and get the old album information. Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are doing is the only way to achieve this. I tried many experiments with the different change/dirty attributes and nothing could get me the "before" version of the record.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Cloud function, providing the old and new album ids, then use `photo.increment()` with +1 / -1 to update the count.